# set a color in bargraph according to if-else statement

Tags: python, plotly

I am working with some json data in python. I want to plot a bargragh such that it will show the color according to a sequence of conditions. I'm running into an issue where only the else condition is ever satisfied.Q['AQI'] has AQI values of different locations,I want color in my graph according AQI color code

Here's the code I'm working from:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

def colors(y):
    color1='#ffff00'#setting default value
    if((Q['AQI']>=51).all() & (Q['AQI']<=100).all()):
        color1='rgb(0,222,0)'
    elif((Q['AQI']>=101).all() & (Q['AQI']<=150).all()):
        color1='rgb(0,0,222)'
    elif((Q['AQI']>=151).all() & (Q['AQI']<=200).all()):
        color1='rgb(0,222,0)'    
    elif((Q['AQI']>=201).all() & (Q['AQI']<=300).all()):
        color1='rgb(222,0,0)'   
    elif((Q['AQI']>=301).all() & (Q['AQI']<=600).all()):
        color1='rgb(0,0,222)'
    else: color1='rgb(222,0,0)'

    return color1

trace0 = go.Bar(x=Q['location'],
                y=Q['AQI'],
                marker=dict(color=colors(y)))
data = [trace0]
fig = go.Figure(data=data)
py.iplot(fig, filename='color-bar')
```

Comment: What does Q['AQI'] look like?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please fix the indentation in your code and make sure you have a [MCVE].

Comment: Maybe change `&` for `and`? That's how you add condition in python's if-statements.